# how to find Connected Component dynamically

Tags: algorithm, boost, graph-theory

Using disjoint-set data structure can easily get connected component of Graph. And, it just supports [Incremental Connected Components](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/incremental_components.html).

However, in my case, removing edge is very common so that I am looking for an algorithm or new  structure can maintain Connected Components **fully dynamically**(including adding and removing edge)

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) has a reference.

Comment: @ n.m. which one? "Undirected connectivity in log-space"?

Comment: "An On-Line Edge-Deletion Problem"

Comment: @n.m.: That time complexity only applies to forests, not general graphs, which still have O(n) time complexity per edge deletion.

Comment: @n.m.: Unfortunately that algorithm handles only edge *deletions*, not both insertions and deletions.

Answer (score 8):

[Poly-logarithmic deterministic fully-dynamic algorithms for connectivity, minimum spanning tree, 2-edge, and biconnectivity (Holm, de Lichtenberg and Thorup 2001)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.919&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives an algorithm that allows an arbitrary sequence of edge insertions, deletions and connectivity queries, with updates (insertions and deletions) taking O(log(n)^2) amortised time, and queries taking O(log(n)/log(log(n))) time, with n being the number of vertices in the graph.  These time bounds assume that the graph starts with no edges.

I only skimmed the first 2 of its 38 pages, but don't be (too) scared -- the paper describes a bunch of new algorithms on *dynamic graphs* (that is, graphs that can be efficiently modified over time) of which connectivity is the simplest.